# How to override inline style dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have the following html code:

`<div title="remove css"style="position:relative;">Remove my style</div>`

I have to remove the `position` style attribute completely after page load. I am in a situation where I can't override the CSS. I have to completely remove `position` style. How is this possible?

Comment: So you can't use css to override it?  Can you use javascript?

Comment: What about adding inline css using JavaScript?

Comment: we can use javascript,jquery . html is populated dynamically. so i can't add inline style manually.

Comment: Don't style all elements of a given type, use classes or an `id` instead. Or set `position: static;` on the element whose CSS you need to 'un-set'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery for this simple task, especially if you are not already using it.

Just put an inline style on the divs, this will override the the pre existing CSS.

```js
function overridePosition() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    len = divs.length,
    i = 0;
  for (; i < len; i += 1) {
    // static is the default value of possition
    divs[i].style.position = 'static';
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', overridePosition);
};
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  Click Me To override position: relative
</button>
<div>
  <div title="remove css">Remove my style</div>
  <div title="remove css">Remove my style</div>
  <div title="remove css">Remove my style</div>
  <div title="remove css">Remove my style</div>
</div>
```

There is a way to actually delete the rule, but I highly, highly recommend not doing it this way. It is not a cross browser solution and in the long term it is more hassle then it's worth.

```js
function deletePosition() {
  var cssRules = document.styleSheets[0];

  // the only reason we know what index the rule is at is because it is the only rule.
  var ruleIndex = 0;
  
  if (typeof cssRules.deleteRule == "function") {
    cssRules.deleteRule(ruleIndex);
  } else if (typeof cssRules.removeRule == "function") {
    cssRules.removeRule(ruleIndex);
  } else {
    // don't know how to remove/delete css rule
  }
}


window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', deletePosition);
};
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  Click Me To delete css position: relative rule
</button>
<div>
  <div title="remove css">Remove my style</div>
  <div title="remove css">Remove my style</div>
  <div title="remove css">Remove my style</div>
  <div title="remove css">Remove my style</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override css like so:

```
$('div').css({'position': 'static'});
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: i aready mention in question,that i don't want to override css. i have to remove completely.

Comment: @MukundKumar **why** do you "have to" remove it completely? What difference does it make?

Comment: If your CSS load from a file it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just set a initial position with CSS, and then on doc ready, `removeClass` using jQuery?

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qq0zdqkv/)

Does this seem like what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

do it using jquery to overwrite the original value

```
$("#ID").css("rule","newvalue");
```

OR
create create a new class with oposite rule 
**the default positioning for all elements is static**
so like this

```
myclass{
position:static!important;   //to overwrite anything else

}
```

then with jquery

```
$("#id").addClass("myclass");
```

Comment: i aready mention in question,that i don't want to override css. i have to remove completely. in my case if i remove position completly then it work, else if i override with any other value, it did not work

Comment: then try something like $(div).css("position",""); it works with color values yet i think it might work with positioning as well

Comment: no,it is not working.it is showng inalid property value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can remove the position property completely using jquery. The code should be:

```
$('div').removeAttr("position");
```